# synchonises Link

Tags: transactions, ejb-3.1

A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB TotoCacheBean,

> method: public void ...TotoCacheBean.refreshAlertCache() ...:
>   ATTENTION: javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted Caused by:
>   javax.transaction.RollbackException at
>   com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:334)

```
@Singleton
@PersistenceContext(name = "persistence/popul", unitName = "popul")
@TransactionAttribute(value = TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)
@Startup
public class TotoCacheBean
{
    private final ReadWriteLock lock    = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

@Inject
private MessageDAO messageDAO;

public enum Type
{
    ALERT, GLOBAL
};

private Map<Type, TotoCache>    cacheStorage;

@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct() throws DAOException
{
    refreshAlertCache();
    refreshGlobalCache();
}

@Schedule(second = "*/20", minute = "*", hour = "*", persistent = false)
public void refreshAlertCache() throws DAOException
{
    refreshCache(Type.ALERT);
}

@Schedule(second = "10", minute = "*", hour = "*", persistent = false)
public void refreshGlobalCache() throws DAOException
{
    refreshCache(Type.GLOBAL);
}       

private void refreshCache(Type type) throws DAOException
{
    Date now = DateTools.getDate();
    LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, ActMessDTO>> messages = messageDAO.getActMessSorted(now, (type == Type.ALERT));
    setCache(type, new TotoCache(messages, now));
}


public TotoCache getCache(Type type)
{
    lock.readLock().lock();

    try
    {
        return getCacheStorage().get(type);
    }
    finally
    {
        lock.readLock().unlock();
    }
}

private void setCache(Type type, TotoCache cache)
{
    lock.writeLock().lock();

    try
    {
        getCacheStorage().put(type, cache);
    }
    finally
    {
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}

private Map<Type, TotoCache> getCacheStorage()
{
    if (this.cacheStorage == null)
        this.cacheStorage = new HashMap<Type, TotoCache>();

    return this.cacheStorage;
}
```

}`

Have you some ideas to resolve the issue? The LinkedHashMap is not synchronized but i prefer not to change it because it will change more than 10 classes. but if it 's the reason i will do it. 
Or the probleme is the use of ReadWriteLock? thanks for your tricks

Answer (score 0):

You are using `ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN` & `TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS` together which are contradictory.

From Documentation :

> It can only be specified if container managed transaction demarcation is used.

Either have `ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER` or manage transactions manually using `UserTransaction` interface.

Refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html) for various attribute types & apply according to your requirement.

> The LinkedHashMap is not synchronized ...

By default, the bean with `@Singleton` will have `LockType.WRITE`.

> LockType.WRITE : For exclusive access to the bean instance.

The singleton session bean will be locked to other clients while a client is calling that method. Therefore explicit control over concurrency isn't required.